# Combine after map and filter two objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two objects mapping then filter want to combine some of the properties after mapped

```
const arr1 = [{id:1,color:"red"},{id:2,color:"blue"},{id:3,color:"black"},{id:4,color:"white"}];
const arr2 = [{value:1,car:"honda",wheel:4},{value:2,car:"oddy",wheel:4},{value:3,car:"audi",wheel:4},{value:4,car:"hundai",wheel:4}]
    
const targetedIDs =arr1.map((d) => d.id);   // [1]
const mappedValues= filter(obj, (item) => includes(targetedIDs,item.value )); 
                                                                 //{"value":1,"car":"honda","wheel":4}
```

But how to get color in the same `id===value`
Expected

```
Expectedresult = {"value":1,"car":"honda","wheel":4,"color":"red"}
```

Comment: You should give us more sample data instead of single.

Comment: obj1 = [{id:1,color:red},{id:2,color:blue,{id:3,color:black},{id:4,color:white}]
obj2 = [{value:1,car:honda,wheel:4},{value:2,car:oddy,wheel:4},{value:3,car:audi,wheel:4},{value:4,car:hundai,wheel:4}]

Comment: You should update the question then check [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67068549/9071943).

Comment: Pls update your expected output `[{"color":"red","value":1,"car":"honda","wheel":4},{"color":"blue","value":2,"car":"oddy","wheel":4},{"color":"black","value":3,"car":"audi","wheel":4},{"color":"white","value":4,"car":"hundai","wheel":4}]` and title to make the question clear to help the reader in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, your `obj1, obj2` is an array.

You can do 2 steps like below:

1. Build `value_mapping`. The content structure will be an object to help us check `arr1's Id`  contain or not with `O(1)` time complexity instead of using `filter` of each loop.

The structure look like:

```
{"1":{"value":1,"car":"honda","wheel":4},"2":{"value":2,"car":"oddy","wheel":4},"3":{"value":3,"car":"audi","wheel":4},"4":{"value":4,"car":"hundai","wheel":4}}
```

2. Using `Array#reduce` to iterate the `arr1`. At each item, you should check whether contain a value of `arr2` or not.

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1,color:"red"},{id:2,color:"blue"},{id:3,color:"black"},{id:4,color:"white"}];
const arr2 = [{value:1,car:"honda",wheel:4},{value:2,car:"oddy",wheel:4},{value:3,car:"audi",wheel:4},{value:4,car:"hundai",wheel:4}]

const value_mapping = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr["value"]] = curr, acc), {});

const mappedValues= arr1.reduce((acc, {id, color}) => {
 if(value_mapping[id])
  acc.push({color: color, ...value_mapping[id]});
 return acc;
}, []);
console.log(mappedValues);
```